# How to Unset the Position of a Sticky Element with Another Element

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is at all possible. However, I have a header that I've stuck to the top of the screen using "position:sticky,top:0".

Is it at all possible to set the position of the header to "relative" when it touches the "sticky" div while scrolling down.

The effect would be that it would be pushed out of the viewport and the "sticky" div would remain in the stuck position as the user continues to scroll down the page. Like some sort of stacking effect.

```
<header id="site-header"></header>
<main>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="sticky"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: They will "stack" already, but not in the way you want, that the first element actually gets pushed out of the viewport. It will _keep_ stuck in place, and the next one will simply position on top of it, on the z axis. The behavior you want, won't be possible without involving additional JavaScript.